# Autofit text under image with only css

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to lay out some text under an image in such a way that the image determines the width of the container and the text wraps into several lines to fit the width.

My current code looks like this:

```css
.image-container {
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
 background-color: red; /* To highlight container size */
}

.image {
 height: 120px;
}

.text-wrapper {
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
}

.text {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:100%;
 right:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='image-container'>
 <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
 <div class='text-wrapper'>
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

But as you can see, since the text is positioned with absolute, it isn't part of the container height, making it impossible to correctly layout on the rest of my page.

How do I solve this correctly? I'd rather lose some browser compatibility than use js btw.

Comment: Do you not know the width of the image?

Comment: No, the width can (will!) vary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```css
.image-container {
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}

img {
  height: 120px;
}

.text {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='image-container'>
 <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
 <div class='text-wrapper'>
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is another solution you could try

```css
.image-container {
  display: table;
}

img {
  height: 120px;
}

.text-wrapper {
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class='image-container'>
 <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
 <div class='text-wrapper'>
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, it works! How does it work though? Why doesn't the p tag expand the width of the container?

Comment: I think its because table width is fixed so css will break text but it cant break image `:)` ...

Comment: Ah, very sneaky! :) I do need the element to be inline though, but wrapping the div inside inline-block div produces some weird width, any idea what it is (see image)? http://i.imgur.com/lIFyRn4.png

Comment: I am not sure, i suggest that you ask that as another question https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/328/, but other solution work fine https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/329/ but its kinda more risky in terms of browser support.

Comment: Ah, table-caption seems to be supported from IE8, which is fine! And yes, great movie :) I'll add another question as well!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34187128/why-does-these-inline-block-element-produce-extra-width