# Why does these inline-block element produce extra width?

Tags: html, css

This is a follow up from this question: [Autofit text under image with only css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185547/autofit-text-under-image-with-only-css)

Why does the inline-block divs in this code produce extra width on the right side of the elements?

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.image-container {
  background-color: blue;
  display: table;
  width: 1%;
}

img {
  height: 120px;
}

.text-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
    <div class='text-wrapper'>
      <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
    <div class='text-wrapper'>
      <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
    <div class='text-wrapper'>
      <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class='image-container'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
    <div class='text-wrapper'>
      <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: This is NOT a problem with whitespace, see this jsfiddle without any whitespace and notice that the div still takes up lots of extra space (the red area): https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/332/

Edit2: To clarify my requirements: I have N images with varying width that I wish to layout in a "dynamic table", i.e. the images should be inline so they will automatically wrap when running out of horizontal space in parent. Where this gets tricky is that I have some text that I wish to display under each image that should wrap with the image width as well (and as I said, the image width may vary).

Comment: That's the width of your container if you hadn't applied the display:table to it. It's the space that the text normally occupies.

Comment: why are you using `display:table`?

Comment: @j08691 yes, I figured that as well, but isn't that very buggy behaviour?

Comment: @Martin see the linked question.

Comment: @Michael_B OP is talking about the red space. Doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. Chrome and Firefox both give the `inline-block` div a width in the 300px range.

Comment: What about this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/335/

Comment: Problem is that since item is no longer inline-block, but table-cell, it won't automatically flow into the next line when the parent width is reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red portion of the item is an artifact of the browser not knowing how to correctly size the containers. It's using the length of the text to determine the width before the table layout is applied. If you know the width of the items, you can use this simpler approach:

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 120px;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src='http://i.imgur.com/nV2qBpe.jpg' class="image">
  <p class='text'>Some text that may need to wrap into multiple lines</p>
</div>
```

I don't know off hand of a way to make the elements shrink to the smallest possible width while still containing all child elements.

Comment: According to the other post the OP linked to he doesn't know the image's width or it can vary.

Comment: Good to know. I'm not in the habit of following rabbit trails. If that information is important, it should be in the question rather than in a supplemental link.

Comment: Yeah, I did another edit to clarify my requirements.

Comment: I used variable text and that proved to be why the `inline-block` stuff had unexpected width. https://jsfiddle.net/tewn7mjm/

Comment: Accepting this as answer as you explained why the divs got that magic width. See @Anthony's answer for best working example of what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Brandon Gano's second answer. I used `display: table-caption;` on `.text-wrapper`.

Here's the CSS I modified from his jsfiddle:

```
.text-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  height: 60px;             /* You may have to modify the height */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

And the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rofe2op/).

Comment: Now just have text-wrapper have automatic height and still align.. ;) Just kiddin'! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Anytime! Glad to help :)

Answer (score -3):

You're seeing whitespace added between the `inline-block` elements. You can remove the horizontal space between these items by removing all whitespace between the elements. e.g.:

```
<div>
  ...
</div><div>
  ...
</div><div>
  ...
</div>
```

Note that the closing tag is immediately followed by the next opening tag.

Comment: I tried exactly that... but nope.  Isn't the OP talking about that red zone?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the red zone, so this doesn't fix it :(